# python re.sub regex

Tags: python, regex

Python keeps returning a string with a broken character.

python

```
test = re.sub('handle(.*?)', '<verse osisID="lol">\1</verse>', 'handle a bunch of random text here.')
print test
```

what I want

```
<verse osisID="lol">a bunch of random text here.</verse>
```

what i am getting

```
<verse osisID="lol">*broken character*</verse>a bunch of random text here.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should either escape the `\` character or use a `r''` raw string:

```
>>> re.sub('handle(.*?)', r'<verse osisID="lol">\1</verse>', 'handle a bunch of random text here.')
'<verse osisID="lol"></verse> a bunch of random text here.'
```

Without the `r''` raw string literal, backslashes are interpreted as escape codes. You can double the backslash as well:

```
>>> '\1'
'\x01'
>>> '\\1'
'\\1'
>>> r'\1'
'\\1'
>>> print r'\1'
\1
```

Note that you replace just the word `handle` there, the `.*?` pattern matches 0 characters at minimum. Remove the question mark and it'll match your expected output:

```
>>> re.sub('handle(.*)', r'<verse osisID="lol">\1</verse>', 'handle a bunch of random text here.')
'<verse osisID="lol"> a bunch of random text here.</verse>'
```

Comment: you are a beautiful person :)

Comment: you might want to match the space after the `handle` but before the next word as well, as this will prevent the `...> a br...`  You could do this with  `handle *(.*)` presuming you only have spaces (not other whitespace)

Comment: @AndrewCox: I'd use `\s*` to match whitespace there instead; why limit only to spaces?

Answer (score 0):

below code tested under python 3.6

```
import re 

test = 'a bunch of random text here.'
resp = re.sub(r'(.*)',r'<verse osisID="lol">\1</verse>',test)
print (resp)

<verse osisID="lol">a bunch of random text here.</verse>
```